# What can I do to solve the npm "Cannot find module 'util-deprecate'" error?

Tags: node.js, npm, server, web-development-server

While install a module using NPM, this error showed up.
**

### Error: Cannot find module 'util-deprecate'

**
I uninstalled and reinstalled the entire Node.js but every attempt to install modules using NPM was futile and every time same error keeps popping up.

Windows 10 with latest Node.js 12.18.3

Comment: Which versions of node/npm are you using?  And which OS?

Comment: Have u tried clear the `npm` cache nd trying ?

Comment: Can you add screen short and declaration of part `util-deprecate` here

Answer (score 2):

Install NVM and use the correct version of Node.JS
https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm

~ nvm usw 11

Solved the OP's error for me.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I resolved the issue myself.
While updating the NPM using command line, the update crashed and many files within the **C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules** were deleted.
Solution would be to copy the missing modules from Node Modules within npm of Node Js directory in Program Files (Windows). It will work for sure.
Thank you.